# Issue with fitting an R, L, C equation to measured data with Scipy optimize

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit an equation for transmission line attenuation using Python. I am trying to do this by importing a measured data

Equation `alpha= ((r+2j*pi*f*l)*2j*pi*f*c)^0.5`, where r, l, and c are resistance, inductance and capacitance.

Below, I adapted a code I found on stack overflow and modified it it to fit my specific problem. Still learning Python. The original code generates its own data and fit it to an equation. But in my case I imported a measured data and fit it with the equation to extract r, l and c parameters.

The issue is the fit is not trying to fit follow the data. It is only a starting function. I have to somehow link the fit to the data in a code I guess.

I greatly appreciate if someone can help.

[image: curve fitting of equation]

```py
import math
from numpy import loadtxt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#Import the measured data

data = loadtxt("C:/Users/att_data.txt")
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]

# Plot the measured data:
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlim((0,30))
plt.xlabel('Frequency [GHz]')
plt.ylabel('Attenuation')
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)
plt.title('Measurement data')
plt.show()

# Define Equation for attenuation
def alpha( x, r,l,c ):
    w=2*math.pi*x
    a=r+1j*w*l
    b=1j*w*c
    y = (a*b)**0.5.real
    return y

def alpha_real( x, r,l,c ):
    return alpha( x , r, l, c ).real

#scale some parameters
def alpha_real_milli_nano( x , r, l, c ):
    return alpha_real( x , r, 1e-6 * l, 1e-9 * c ).real

# Generated data
wList = np.linspace( 0, 30, 25 )
wFullList = np.linspace( 0, 30, 301)

rComplexList = np.fromiter( ( alpha(x, 13000, 4.14e-7, 1.3e-10) for x in wList ), complex)
rList = np.fromiter( ( r.real for r in rComplexList ), float )
pList = np.fromiter( ( np.angle( r ) for r in rComplexList ), float )

fit, pcov=curve_fit(alpha_real_milli_nano, wList, rList)
print (fit)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( x, y , ls='', marker='o', label=' Measured data')
ax.plot( wList, rList , ls='', marker='o', label='Generated data')
ax.plot( wFullList, [ alpha_real( x , *fit ) for x in wFullList ], label='fit')
ax.legend( loc=0 )
plt.show()
```

Data are below:

`C:/Users/att_data.txt`

```
0       24.2
0.1     58.2
0.2     88.2
0.3     105.9
0.4     120.4
0.5     131.6
0.6     141.1
0.7     149.6
0.8     157.4
0.9     164.3
1       170.5
1.1     176.3
1.2     181.9
1.3     186.9
1.4     191.4
1.5     195.8
1.6     199.8
1.7     203.6
1.8     207.5
1.9     211.0
2       214.5
2.1     217.9
2.2     221.0
2.3     223.9
2.4     226.9
2.5     229.8
2.6     232.4
2.7     235.1
2.8     237.7
2.9     240.1
3       242.3
3.1     244.6
3.2     246.7
3.3     248.7
3.4     250.8
3.5     252.8
3.6     254.7
3.7     256.6
3.8     258.4
3.9     260.1
4       261.8
4.1     262.8
4.2     264.1
4.3     265.6
4.4     267.2
4.5     268.6
4.6     270.1
4.7     271.8
4.8     273.1
4.9     274.4
5       275.7
5.1     276.9
5.2     278.2
5.3     279.6
5.4     280.9
5.5     281.8
5.6     283.1
5.7     284.3
5.8     285.4
5.9     286.7
6       287.9
6.1     289.0
6.2     290.0
6.3     291.3
6.4     292.3
6.5     293.3
6.6     294.3
6.7     295.2
6.8     296.4
6.9     298.0
7       298.8
7.1     299.7
7.2     300.6
7.3     301.4
7.4     302.2
7.5     303.0
7.6     303.9
7.7     304.6
7.8     305.3
7.9     305.9
8       306.5
8.1     306.9
8.2     307.5
8.3     308.3
8.4     309.1
8.5     309.9
8.6     310.5
8.7     311.1
8.8     312.0
8.9     312.6
9       313.2
9.1     314.0
9.2     314.7
9.3     315.4
9.4     316.1
9.5     316.7
9.6     317.3
9.7     317.9
9.8     318.7
9.9     319.4
10      320.2
10.1    320.8
10.2    321.3
10.3    322.1
10.4    322.5
10.5    323.1
10.6    323.9
10.7    324.6
10.8    325.3
10.9    325.9
11      326.7
11.1    327.0
11.2    327.6
11.3    328.3
11.4    328.7
11.5    329.5
11.6    330.2
11.7    330.7
11.8    331.2
11.9    331.8
12      332.5
12.1    333.4
12.2    334.1
12.3    334.5
12.4    334.8
12.5    335.6
12.6    335.8
12.7    336.1
12.8    336.7
12.9    336.9
13      337.4
13.1    337.9
13.2    338.2
13.3    338.4
13.4    338.6
13.5    338.9
13.6    338.8
13.7    339.0
13.8    339.2
13.9    339.1
14      339.4
14.1    339.7
14.2    339.9
14.3    339.9
14.4    340.4
14.5    340.8
14.6    341.2
14.7    341.7
14.8    342.3
14.9    342.8
15      343.2
15.1    343.5
15.2    344.0
15.3    344.4
15.4    344.4
15.5    344.5
15.6    344.7
15.7    344.9
15.8    344.8
15.9    345.0
16      345.2
16.1    345.2
16.2    345.6
16.3    345.9
16.4    346.1
16.5    346.2
16.6    346.5
16.7    346.7
16.8    346.8
16.9    347.4
17      347.5
17.1    347.7
17.2    348.1
17.3    348.1
17.4    348.3
17.5    348.6
17.6    349.2
17.7    349.3
17.8    349.5
17.9    349.7
18      349.7
18.1    350.2
18.2    350.6
18.3    350.7
18.4    351.1
18.5    351.3
18.6    351.5
18.7    351.9
18.8    352.0
18.9    352.1
19      352.4
19.1    353.1
19.2    353.0
19.3    353.0
19.4    353.2
19.5    352.7
19.6    352.9
19.7    353.3
19.8    353.3
19.9    353.1
20      352.5
20.1    351.6
20.2    351.1
20.3    350.8
20.4    350.5
20.5    350.2
20.6    350.2
20.7    350.0
20.8    349.8
20.9    349.8
21      349.8
21.1    349.6
21.2    349.5
21.3    349.6
21.4    349.6
21.5    349.6
21.6    349.6
21.7    349.2
21.8    349.0
21.9    349.0
22      349.2
22.1    349.5
22.2    349.9
22.3    350.3
22.4    350.8
22.5    351.3
22.6    351.7
22.7    352.3
22.8    353.3
22.9    354.2
23      354.8
23.1    354.9
23.2    354.7
23.3    354.5
23.4    354.5
23.5    354.8
23.6    355.9
23.7    357.0
23.8    358.0
23.9    357.8
24      358.1
24.1    358.6
24.2    359.0
24.3    359.0
24.4    358.6
24.5    357.9
24.6    357.4
24.7    357.2
24.8    356.9
24.9    356.4
25      356.2
25.1    356.1
25.2    356.4
25.3    357.4
25.4    358.0
25.5    358.2
25.6    358.1
25.7    357.6
25.8    357.4
25.9    357.4
26      357.5
26.1    357.4
26.2    357.5
26.3    357.4
26.4    356.6
26.5    356.8
26.6    357.2
26.7    357.5
26.8    357.1
26.9    357.2
27      357.6
27.1    357.9
27.2    357.2
27.3    357.2
27.4    357.4
27.5    357.5
27.6    357.6
27.7    357.7
27.8    357.8
27.9    357.8
28      357.6
28.1    357.8
28.2    358.4
28.3    358.3
28.4    358.5
28.5    358.9
28.6    359.0
28.7    359.4
28.8    359.7
28.9    359.8
29      360.1
29.1    360.9
29.2    361.6
29.3    362.0
29.4    362.9
29.5    363.5
29.6    364.1
29.7    364.7
29.8    365.1
29.9    365.8
30      366.8
```

Modified a code to fit data; I expected the curve fit to be minimizing the difference between the measured and trial curve.

---

This is a follow-up question on the on the above with modified equations.

I have been trying to fit the Z0 data to an equation. I used the same code suggest by @Reinderien but the fit is not happening.

The values used for trial function are close enough to fit the data. I was wonering if I am doing something wrong.

Below is the code and the data. The issue is I don't see a trial curve. The best I was able to get to fitting is the below.

```
  [![Curve fit trial][1]][1]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

f, alpha_measured = np.loadtxt(fname='C:/Users/Z0.txt').T
f *= 1e9  # GHz

def alpha_model(f: np.ndarray, C: float, Rs: float, Cs: 
    float) -> np.ndarray:
    s = 2j*np.pi*f
    Cs_ = Cs / (1 + Rs ** 2 * Cs ** 2 * (s/1j)**2)
    Gs_ = (Rs * Cs ** 2 * (s/1j)** 2) / (1 + Rs ** 2 * Cs 
    ** 2 * (s/1j)**2)
    R=20000
    L=400e-7
    Z1 = R+s*L
    Y1 = Gs_ + s*(Cs_+C)
    print(Cs_)
    Z0 = np.sqrt(Z1/Y1)
    alpha = Z0.real
    return alpha

    
    p0 = (1.5e-12, 3e4, 1e-12)

   (C, Rs, Cs), _ = curve_fit(f=alpha_model, 
    method='lm',`enter code here`xdata=f, 
   ydata=alpha_measured, p0=p0)

   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   ax.plot(f, alpha_measured, '.', label='Measured')
   ax.plot(f, alpha_measured, '.', label='Measured')
   ax.plot(f, alpha_model(f, *p0), label='Guess')
   plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
   plt.ylabel('Impedance[Ohms]')
   ax.plot(f, alpha_model(f, C, Rs, Cs), '.- 
   ',label='Fit')
   ax.set_title(f'C~{C:.1e} ,Rs~{Rs:.1e} Ω, Cs~{Cs:.1e} 
   F') 
   ax.legend()
   plt.show()
```

Data is below

```
0.1   91.99052134
0.2   70.54121488
0.3   60.76796774
0.4   55.30267231
0.5   52.03408753
0.6   49.80530727
0.7   48.18825519
0.8   46.90022909
0.9   45.9430654
1     45.23298697
1.1   44.71107729
1.2   44.26193788
1.3   43.88725769
1.4   43.58713396
1.5   43.38000981
1.6   43.21115349
1.7   43.07598121
1.8   42.97275676
1.9   42.90804925
2     42.86889664
2.1   42.8505013
2.2   42.84856829
2.3   42.8661417
2.4   42.88831075
2.5   42.91862623
2.6   42.98203997
2.7   43.02835759
2.8   43.08211324
2.9   43.15255463
3     43.22652434
3.1   43.29457247
3.2   43.36270701
3.3   43.4387327
3.4   43.49349725
3.5   43.56178562
3.6   43.64362255
3.7   43.72676446
3.8   43.81747625
3.9   43.90516886
4     43.98471475
4.1   44.04616093
4.2   44.11574242
4.3   44.19279252
4.4   44.27894232
4.5   44.39619823
4.6   44.50000979
4.7   44.58597495
4.8   44.65505595
4.9   44.71066032
5     44.77355594
5.1   44.85277597
5.2   44.94917911
5.3   45.03081967
5.4   45.10329379
5.5   45.17210128
5.6   45.21946666
5.7   45.27664834
5.8   45.34309776
5.9   45.40465355
6     45.4742799
6.1   45.54324542
6.2   45.60785114
6.3   45.65985862
6.4   45.71730313
6.5   45.77547637
6.6   45.82892432
6.7   45.90241205
6.8   45.96624557
6.9   46.02026233
7     46.07609982
7.1   46.11559209
7.2   46.15682115
7.3   46.20740255
7.4   46.26606292
7.5   46.3238936
7.6   46.37922324
7.7   46.42962463
7.8   46.46141032
7.9   46.49872087
8     46.54174788
8.1   46.58147815
8.2   46.63500109
8.3   46.69175085
8.4   46.74731254
8.5   46.7895724
8.6   46.82926053
8.7   46.86615028
8.8   46.89972648
8.9   46.94686994
9     46.99044437
9.1   47.03181441
9.2   47.08349584
9.3   47.12035882
9.4   47.15050909
9.5   47.17664913
9.6   47.19694384
9.7   47.22850624
9.8   47.27093932
9.9   47.32551361
10    47.36123856
10.1  47.38959149
10.2  47.41311968
10.3  47.43628115
10.4  47.47634331
10.5  47.51643761
10.6  47.55048347
10.7  47.59507364
10.8  47.63618469
10.9  47.66943594
11    47.68791069
11.1  47.70147674
11.2  47.71968076
11.3  47.74709933
11.4  47.79773737
11.5  47.83616503
11.6  47.8645716
11.7  47.88306644
11.8  47.88820781
11.9  47.90434828
12    47.93000338
12.1  47.96509807
12.2  48.0027716
12.3  48.0415887
12.4  48.07717939
12.5  48.09298612
12.6  48.09898714
12.7  48.10516994
12.8  48.1168162
12.9  48.15785543
13    48.19181624
13.1  48.21346271
13.2  48.21394309
13.3  48.21086954
13.4  48.21065686
13.5  48.21550757
13.6  48.23166294
13.7  48.2467202
13.8  48.26081058
13.9  48.27364852
14    48.27910776
14.1  48.27431147
14.2  48.26487774
14.3  48.25695286
14.4  48.28323596
14.5  48.31395965
14.6  48.34019803
14.7  48.34140569
14.8  48.34913651
14.9  48.35855417
15    48.36865118
15.1  48.39360616
15.2  48.42207912
15.3  48.45216644
15.4  48.48163962
15.5  48.5050621
15.6  48.51535767
15.7  48.51696294
15.8  48.52823028
15.9  48.54908443
16    48.57840965
16.1  48.61510491
16.2  48.63863158
16.3  48.65470891
16.4  48.66320056
16.5  48.66230003
16.6  48.66269972
16.7  48.67476602
16.8  48.69563704
16.9  48.71188207
17    48.70927721
17.1  48.69576764
17.2  48.67389916
17.3  48.66876069
17.4  48.67289148
17.5  48.68308794
17.6  48.69659017
17.7  48.6993241
17.8  48.69679291
17.9  48.6905476
18    48.68376301
18.1  48.67846688
18.2  48.67627018
18.3  48.67799656
18.4  48.68321348
18.5  48.69004411
18.6  48.69230327
18.7  48.68166392
18.8  48.6769084
18.9  48.6794062
19    48.6879789
19.1  48.6981749
19.2  48.70292387
19.3  48.70776869
19.4  48.71537633
19.5  48.73510814
19.6  48.74757652
19.7  48.75570203
19.8  48.76202376
19.9  48.7696686
20    48.7758261
20.1  48.77981694
20.2  48.7799139
20.3  48.78088379
20.4  48.78345633
20.5  48.78758334
20.6  48.78512418
20.7  48.77967036
20.8  48.7738807
20.9  48.77083238
21    48.7682265
21.1  48.77119652
21.2  48.77856342
21.3  48.78472081
21.4  48.78570046
21.5  48.78053837
21.6  48.76917009
21.7  48.76732098
21.8  48.77042927
21.9  48.78284589
22    48.81117441
22.1  48.83412416
22.2  48.84231325
22.3  48.83809719
22.4  48.83071562
22.5  48.83249014
22.6  48.8418601
22.7  48.85839525
22.8  48.87681081
22.9  48.88743496
23    48.88780884
23.1  48.87293953
23.2  48.85896611
23.3  48.8535035
23.4  48.86281964
23.5  48.90825925
23.6  48.95398898
23.7  48.98063906
23.8  48.98109141
23.9  48.96443187
24    48.95899773
24.1  48.96641863
24.2  48.99099484
24.3  49.00665852
24.4  49.01637126
24.5  49.01917304
24.6  49.00931662
24.7  48.98568369
24.8  48.96468054
24.9  48.95377179
25    48.97487697
25.1  49.00718234
25.2  49.03636794
25.3  49.04622633
25.4  49.03679742
25.5  49.0364527
25.6  49.04934122
25.7  49.08237539
25.8  49.11156871
25.9  49.12826087
26    49.12883959
26.1  49.11348074
26.2  49.07896867
26.3  49.04024879
26.4  49.0141487
26.5  49.03138489
26.6  49.06931364
26.7  49.11619974
26.8  49.1420456
26.9  49.14890798
27    49.14104989
27.1  49.12135713
27.2  49.137285
27.3  49.17422115
27.4  49.22641786
27.5  49.28966757
27.6  49.3190337
27.7  49.32323732
27.8  49.30956847
27.9  49.29511272
28    49.29816725
28.1  49.30729014
28.2  49.31831822
28.3  49.32372917
28.4  49.32780005
28.5  49.32357257
28.6  49.30185088
28.7  49.27020141
28.8  49.24853453
28.9  49.24069784
29    49.25639585
29.1  49.27405585
29.2  49.28352727
29.3  49.28082592
29.4  49.26494235
29.5  49.24657904
29.6  49.23172844
29.7  49.22795941
29.8  49.24799699
29.9  49.27051898
30    49.29127279
30.1  49.30229847
30.2  49.29330313
30.3  49.28046532
30.4  49.26929584
30.5  49.26455401
30.6  49.25559815
30.7  49.24656057
30.8  49.24197855
30.9  49.23683548
31    49.22162498
31.1  49.2004693
31.2  49.18912037
31.3  49.19691724
31.4  49.21320731
31.5  49.2328318
31.6  49.22685882
31.7  49.21111763
31.8  49.19172457
31.9  49.1744217
32    49.16225875
32.1  49.1572244
32.2  49.15967341
32.3  49.17125919
32.4  49.17580305
32.5  49.15916224
32.6  49.12036512
32.7  49.13783428
32.8  49.15022277
32.9  49.16305143
33    49.1820502
33.1  49.19268356
33.2  49.1969796
33.3  49.19571071
33.4  49.18980925
33.5  49.16880216
33.6  49.14581446
33.7  49.12696138
33.8  49.14311135
33.9  49.17231416
34    49.20062157
34.1  49.21357182
34.2  49.2083246
34.3  49.19366212
34.4  49.17464759
34.5  49.16563548
34.6  49.16470254
34.7  49.17552146
34.8  49.19900014
34.9  49.22004727
35    49.22410008
35.1  49.21586488
35.2  49.19751965
35.3  49.18951948
35.4  49.18926868
35.5  49.19429454
35.6  49.19794739
35.7  49.20508615
35.8  49.20564142
35.9  49.19536675
36    49.1654673
36.1  49.14895188
36.2  49.15136858
36.3  49.18264998
36.4  49.22491386
36.5  49.24704317
36.6  49.24743971
36.7  49.22378966
36.8  49.20871012
36.9  49.20219331
37    49.20551778
37.1  49.2271259
37.2  49.25953376
37.3  49.29449793
37.4  49.32398341
37.5  49.3190856
37.6  49.30447262
37.7  49.2872527
37.8  49.28489311
37.9  49.31178855
38    49.34518693
38.1  49.37553275
38.2  49.3734931
38.3  49.35241289
38.4  49.32138594
38.5  49.28730235
38.6  49.28028153
38.7  49.28981465
38.8  49.31087283
38.9  49.33161692
39    49.32887756
39.1  49.31270757
39.2  49.2867665
39.3  49.27376065
39.4  49.27161678
39.5  49.28176439
39.6  49.30805889
39.7  49.34075082
39.8  49.35902016
39.9  49.3589263
40    49.32894387
40.1  49.29183732
40.2  49.27434765
40.3  49.2879056
40.4  49.33693091
40.5  49.37658686
40.6  49.39937498
40.7  49.39581943
40.8  49.36781935
40.9  49.33865113
41    49.31377849
41.1  49.30687449
41.2  49.32384408
41.3  49.34576817
41.4  49.36477796
41.5  49.35558338
41.6  49.31061391
41.7  49.25023789
41.8  49.18984994
41.9  49.17918811
42    49.1943675
42.1  49.22573023
42.2  49.25024904
42.3  49.23850008
42.4  49.21043304
42.5  49.17366723
42.6  49.17056852
42.7  49.1984045
42.8  49.24256418
42.9  49.29050739
43    49.31306589
43.1  49.30868413
43.2  49.28131532
43.3  49.2356566
43.4  49.20503315
43.5  49.16580863
43.6  49.12057595
43.7  49.18526601
43.8  49.21297969
43.9  49.20305327
44    49.1470042
44.1  49.0946957
44.2  49.07055567
44.3  49.07668154
44.4  49.11613498
44.5  49.15897116
44.6  49.182805
44.7  49.17891202
44.8  49.12115063
44.9  49.05781507
45    49.01055384
45.1  49.00746337
45.2  49.07251717
45.3  49.14150319
45.4  49.19540552
45.5  49.1956202
45.6  49.14711136
45.7  49.09534574
45.8  49.05698353
45.9  49.08676402
46    49.14285685
46.1  49.1966483
46.2  49.22230888
46.3  49.17255473
46.4  49.10352213
46.5  49.0329276
46.6  49.0140558
46.7  49.06464639
46.8  49.14501701
46.9  49.23565981
47    49.27236272
47.1  49.24790095
47.2  49.191145
47.3  49.11734177
47.4  49.11616745
47.5  49.17281112
47.6  49.26820661
47.7  49.35285717
47.8  49.34722215
47.9  49.29067058
48    49.19491189
48.1  49.14553037
48.2  49.16342673
48.3  49.22319562
48.4  49.30851934
48.5  49.35085455
48.6  49.32785794
48.7  49.25362973
48.8  49.14237952
48.9  49.08409239
49    49.08054041
49.1  49.13572228
49.2  49.21897198
49.3  49.24792427
49.4  49.22519636
49.5  49.14203145
49.6  49.05796877
49.7  49.02579694
49.8  49.05419066
49.9  49.15525739
50    49.03497498
50.1  48.95230436
50.2  48.95428633
50.3  48.88824726
50.4  48.848112
50.5  48.84891672
50.6  48.91355819
50.7  48.99511205
50.8  49.04220838
50.9  49.05255264
51    49.01840728
51.1  48.97995205
51.2  48.95339716
51.3  48.94951975
51.4  49.01821198
51.5  49.11287938
51.6  49.18978241
51.7  49.21202978
51.8  49.14389663
51.9  49.06863518
52    49.02762357
52.1  49.16453186
52.2  49.23447476
52.3  49.28196908
52.4  49.32088401
52.5  49.32628001
52.6  49.31193281
52.7  49.28804114
52.8  49.26167931
52.9  49.28602372
53    49.33638775
53.1  49.39617245
53.2  49.42721965
53.3  49.4106323
53.4  49.37570898
53.5  49.3244195
53.6  49.21385876
53.7  49.19979927
53.8  49.22442599
53.9  49.24789128
54    49.23704904
54.1  49.25203622
54.2  49.27442612
54.3  49.22615265
54.4  49.17369593
54.5  49.15836559
54.6  49.18533586
54.7  49.19511557
54.8  49.17071708
54.9  49.13179265
55    49.0921622
55.1  49.07322024
55.2  49.0784705
55.3  49.10436737
55.4  49.14183879
55.5  49.17558502
55.6  49.19136923
55.7  49.18760544
55.8  49.19512447
55.9  49.20669102
56    49.21433993
56.1  49.21076149
56.2  49.17948116
56.3  49.13848335
56.4  49.0992511
56.5  49.0942429
56.6  49.10970616
56.7  49.12043722
56.8  49.11813639
56.9  49.08900381
57    49.04138729
57.1  48.98674267
57.2  48.93343067
57.3  48.92932563
57.4  48.942751
57.5  48.96527943
57.6  48.98068604
57.7  48.96612805
57.8  48.94045689
57.9  48.91131914
58    48.91662108
58.1  48.95825356
58.2  49.01336803
58.3  49.06370888
58.4  49.05128368
58.5  49.00668844
58.6  48.94221116
58.7  48.88273556
58.8  48.87548968
58.9  48.90284858
59    48.95714314
59.1  49.00088135
59.2  48.99874025
59.3  48.95710958
59.4  48.87158901
59.5  48.79097627
59.6  48.75113478
59.7  48.75290509
59.8  48.79501049
59.9  48.81378386
60    48.80507936
60.1  48.76563385
60.2  48.67752414
60.3  48.62789232
60.4  48.62322934
60.5  48.67661359
60.6  48.6637267
60.7  48.67195211
60.8  48.67277473
60.9  48.61717888
61    48.55385817
61.1  48.52022322
61.2  48.53390618
61.3  48.62764107
61.4  48.73485091
61.5  48.81187959
61.6  48.82500219
61.7  48.73499549
61.8  48.63944836
61.9  48.55363797
62    48.5238975
62.1  48.55057391
62.2  48.60036163
62.3  48.65791342
62.4  48.66344378
62.5  48.68887694
62.6  48.68636695
62.7  48.60794977
62.8  48.61519233
62.9  48.68206324
63    48.78851401
63.1  48.89223768
63.2  48.90717325
63.3  48.85121611
63.4  48.73234326
63.5  48.63788527
63.6  48.62202329
63.7  48.66003074
63.8  48.73461872
63.9  48.77995324
64    48.77311531
64.1  48.72438253
64.2  48.64848189
64.3  48.62155502
64.4  48.65447241
64.5  48.7862817
64.6  49.30692663
64.7  49.3829847
64.8  49.28279305
64.9  49.14379829
65    48.98367523
65.1  48.87283873
65.2  48.82603955
65.3  48.88030848
65.4  48.97645142
65.5  48.95725642
65.6  48.79723582
65.7  48.75096516
65.8  48.67211933
65.9  48.59554022
66    48.55401481
66.1  48.62212555
66.2  48.73006159
66.3  48.83424167
66.4  48.84897565
66.5  48.74577057
66.6  48.60943956
66.7  48.46339358
66.8  48.43237053
66.9  48.50811224
67    48.63503481
67.1  48.76972327
67.2  48.74285514
67.3  48.64510121
67.4  48.50518398
67.5  48.38721172
67.6  48.37016204
67.7  48.4090169
67.8  48.48465766
67.9  48.53533811
68    48.51509363
68.1  48.44379522
68.2  48.32337763
68.3  48.23664038
68.4  48.22533248
68.5  48.28953004
68.6  48.42210206
68.7  48.50820914
68.8  48.51590017
68.9  48.44034112
69    48.27308891
69.1  48.14679801
69.2  48.07964356
69.3  48.10189312
69.4  48.19863577
69.5  48.26911156
69.6  48.29367068
69.7  48.22742441
69.8  48.11796797
69.9  48.03409286
70    48.02492975
```

Comment: The data seems to saturate. The formula will end up being linear in omega. That's the right description?

Comment: Why is the shunt conductance G missing from the parameter list?

Comment: Do you have a DC measurement for series resistance? Otherwise, this optimization has too many degrees of freedom.

Comment: @Reinderien, Agree that fixing  at least one component would restrict the values. I don't have a DC measurement of the resistance but can look into measurement. R can also be extracted from S-parameters as well as Re{gamma} averaged. It varies 1-20kOhms/m.

Comment: I meant to say R=Re{Z0*gamma} both of which can be extracted from S-parameter measurements indicated in Microwave Eng. by Pozar.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable names are all over the place - use standard names from the literature for your quantities.

Most importantly, `lm` method performs better for `curve_fit` on your data.

"Tell the truth" about your value scales, including that your input data are actually multiples of GHz. If and when you are able to further constrain this system based on physical measurements (probably of R) and you have some idea as to the ballpark of L and C, then scaling them would be reasonable. For now I have omitted it because it's clearer when the physical quantities are on their natural scale, and it does not harm convergence.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def alpha_model(f: np.ndarray, R: float, L: float, C: float) -> np.ndarray:
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constant#Definition
    s = 2j*np.pi*f
    Z = R + s*L
    Y = s*C
    gamma = np.sqrt(Z*Y)
    alpha = gamma.real
    return alpha


f, alpha_measured = np.loadtxt(fname='att_data.txt').T
f *= 1e9  # GHz
p0 = (1e9, 1e-2, 1e-14)
(R, L, C), _ = curve_fit(
    f=alpha_model,
    xdata=f, ydata=alpha_measured, p0=p0,
    method='lm',
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(f, alpha_measured, label='Measured')
ax.plot(f, alpha_model(f, *p0), label='Guess')
ax.plot(f, alpha_model(f, R, L, C), label='Fit')
ax.set_title(
    f'R~{R/1e9:.1f} GΩ, L~{L/1e-3:.0f} mH, C~{C/1e-15:.1f} fF'
)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: fit]

But critically, your model seems to be missing shunt conductance G, which is why R appears so massive:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def alpha_model(f: np.ndarray, R: float, G: float, L: float, C: float) -> np.ndarray:
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constant#Definition
    s = 2j*np.pi*f
    Z = R + s*L
    Y = G + s*C
    gamma = np.sqrt(Z*Y)
    alpha = gamma.real
    return alpha


f, alpha_measured = np.loadtxt(fname='att_data.txt').T
f *= 1e9  # GHz
p0 = (100, 100, 100e-9, 1e-9)
(R, G, L, C), _ = curve_fit(
    f=alpha_model, method='lm',
    xdata=f, ydata=alpha_measured, p0=p0,
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(f, alpha_measured, label='Measured')
ax.plot(f, alpha_model(f, *p0), label='Guess')
ax.plot(f, alpha_model(f, R, G, L, C), label='Fit')
ax.set_title(f'R~{R:.1e} Ω, G~{G:.1e} S, L~{L:.1e} H, C~{C:.1e} F')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: fit with conductance]

Comment: Hi @Reinderien, thank you so much for your quick response, and a compact code and a good fit. I appreciate also the feedback on using standard microwave notations. This is a small portion of the data. I will run the code with full data and let you know.

Comment: Thanks you so much for update in the equation and results. The values now appear to be close to what I expect when you include the shunt G. You are right, I mission G. I will include it later.

Comment: From my experience on non-linear fits. Always scale if you can. ;)

Comment: One  may use the `unpack` option of `np.loadtxt()`...but doesn't make a big difference.

Comment: @mikuszefski Normally scaling would be a good idea. Here it's a bit of a mess because it's an underdetermined fit, and so any scale isn't guaranteed to be respected. If and when OP is able to constrain one of the easier parameters like R based on physical measurements, scaling would be a good idea.

Comment: ;) Isn't (non-linear) fitting an underdetermined system almost always a bad idea, independent of scaling or not.? Cheers